# Substitute specification with markings - clean version

Tags: specification, substitute

I'd like to be clear when responding to a Notice to File Corrected Application Papers. The required item is: "...The substitute specification must be submitted with markings and be accompanied by a clean version (without markings) as set forth in 37 CFR 1.125(c) and a statement that the substitute specification contains no new matter (see 37 CFR 1.125(b)). The specification, claims, and/or abstract page(s) submitted is not acceptable and cannot be scanned or property stored because: The line spacing on the specification, claims, and/or abstract is not 1-1/2 or double spaced (see 37 CFR 1.52(b))."

Perhaps I'm over-thinking this. What is meant by the phrase "submitted with markings and be accompanied by a clean version (without markings)"? Is it only necessary to submit a response where the line spacing of the specification, claims, and/or abstract is double spaced?

Answer (score 2):

The markings do not apply to you if line spacing is the only change to your documents. Submitting the corrected documents and including a note to the examiner about no new matter should satisfy the request. See [posting](http://www.intelproplaw.com/ip_forum/index.php/topic,6882.0.html).